# c#.NET - Extracting raw pixel data with lockbits

Tags: c#, .net, lockbits

I'm making a program to automatically perform certain edits on images.

One of the functions is converting "white" pixels to "white" and transparent. Initially, all is well.

I have managed to convert a 24bppRGB image to a 32bppRGB image with the required pixels all transparent.

The image loads in picturebox and can be opened once saved.

The problem arose when I tried to re-edit the file. When I tried to extract the raw pixel data again, I got nothing. As far as I can tell the entire pixel data array is 0's.

Why is this the case?

^This is my main question.
Outside of that problem, I also noticed a few quirks with the program, these are just out of curiosity:

What's the difference between:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (x + 1); i += y)
```

and

```
for(int i = 0; i <= (x); i += y)
```

And also:

```
byte = 4;
for(int i = 0; i < x - byte; i += byte)
```

and

```
for(int i = 0; i < x - byte; i += 4)
```

The 2nd one caused a AccessViolationException when I unlocked the bitmap.

If possible, keep the explanation as simple as possible. I'm a fairly new at this.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could it be a mismatch of `PixelFormat` in the call to LockBits, when opening the 32bppARGB image?

Comment: I added code formatting to your question, but the second set of `for` loops don't make sense as a question, you may need to clarify.

Comment: Hmm, I try to use bmp.PixelFormat as well as PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb. Neither produced an image.

Comment: That's strange, bmp.PixelFormat should definately work. Could you upload a 32bpp image somewhere so I can take a look?

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/240428/Work-with-bitmap-faster-with-Csharp) is a little tip with example, how to work with bitmaps easily.

p.s. difference between:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (x + 1); i += y)
```

and

```
for(int i = 0; i <= (x); i += y)
```

depends on **y** value.